# how to add 'active' class to the tabs on button click event in materializecss

Tags: materialize

I am using the tabs from materialize Css  for designing user-interface for my personal website, i wanted to use button in content section to add active class to the tab-menu on button click event. can anyone help me with that please!

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](http://materializecss.com/tabs.html) calling select_tab method will do the work.

*$('ul.tabs').tabs('select_tab', 'tab_id');*

Answer (score 0):

```
 // init materialize tab
  var elem = $('.tabs')


  var options = {duration: 600}
  var init_tabs = M.Tabs.init(elem, options);
  var instance_tabs = M.Tabs.getInstance(elem);
```

then you can do this 'list' is one of your tab ID

```
  instance_tabs.select('list');
```